# Run shell command when render is complete (After Effects)

Tags: shell, after-effects

is there a way to programmatically run a shell command after a render has completed in Adobe After effects?

Comment: On windows ? On mac ? Did you try something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Execute a command line from After Effects

You can execute a command line with the `sysmte.callSystem(cmdLineToExecute)` function. Go see the [After Effects Scripting Guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) page **180** section **System callSystem() method**.

Here is an exemple whith a  `echo` command : (`callSystem`returns the command line return's) :

```
var commandOutput = system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c echo hi ");
alert(commandOutput);
```

This will output

> hi

What is after `/c` is the command to execute in the cmd.

A more complex exemple from the scripting guide which get the system time :

```
var timeStr = system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c \"time /t\"");
alert("Current time is " + timeStr);
```

This will output

> Curent time is 11:28

### Open a command line from After Effects

Now if you are looking to open a command line in another window, you have to set the `cmdLineToExecute` as if you were in a command line.

On windows, if you want to open a command line in another window, you have to do this :

```
start cmd.exe
```

So if you want to do it from After

```
system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe ");
```

### Open a command line when the render is done in After Effects

This is a mix with @fabiantheblind's answer.

```
// Create a comp with a solid
var comp = app.project.items.addComp('test', 100, 100, 1, 1, 12);
comp.layers.addSolid([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 'solid', 100, 100, 1, 1);
// Add the comp to the render queue
var rq_item = app.project.renderQueue.items.add(comp);
rq_item.outputModule(1).file = File('~/Desktop/out.mov');
rq_item.render = true;
// Set a function which will be called every frame when the comp will be rendering
// A boolean to be sure that the function called at the end is called once
var called = false;
rq_item.onStatusChanged = function() {
  while (rq_item.status === RQItemStatus.RENDERING) {
    // Is rendering...
    $.writeln('Rendering');

  }

  // When the render is finished
  if (!called && rq_item.status === RQItemStatus.DONE) {
    called = true;
    system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe ");
  }

};
// Launch the render
app.project.renderQueue.render();

// If something goes wrong
app.onError = function(err) {
  $.writeln('ERROR ' + err);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. The only thing you need to investigate is why the `(rq_item.status === RQItemStatus.DONE)` gets called twice.

```
// Create a comp with a solid
var comp = app.project.items.addComp('test', 100, 100, 1, 1, 12);
comp.layers.addSolid([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 'solid', 100, 100, 1, 1);
// Add the comp to the render queue
var rq_item = app.project.renderQueue.items.add(comp);
rq_item.outputModule(1).file = File('~/Desktop/out.mov');
rq_item.render = true;
// Set a function which will be called every frame when the comp will be rendering
// A boolean to be sure that the function called at the end is called once
var called = false;
rq_item.onStatusChanged = function() {
  while (rq_item.status === RQItemStatus.RENDERING) {
    // Is rendering...
    $.writeln('Rendering');

  }

  // When the render is finished
  if (!called && rq_item.status === RQItemStatus.DONE) {
    called = true;
    $.writeln('Done rendering');
    // test for Mac or Win
    var res = null;
    if($.os.charAt (0) === 'M'){
      res = system.callSystem('echo "Hello Mac World"');
    }else{
      res = system.callSystem('cmd.exe /c echo "Hello Win World"');
    }
    $.writeln(res);
  }

};
// Launch the render
app.project.renderQueue.render();

// If something goes wrong
app.onError = function(err) {
  $.writeln('ERROR ' + err);
};
```

Comment: @Kevin. Is it not? It got called twice when I ran it. BTW Thanks for the edits. I was a bit lazy with comments. :-)

Comment: Weird, it must be a synchronization issue, to solve it, you can create a boolean out of the function and set it to true when the render is done the first time.